# Disable a Function jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, function

On Resize, I either call desktop Or mobile. I have a click function in each and they both seem to be running, if it was in desktop and then changes to mobile.  I need to turn off desktop function if the mobile function is true and vice versa.

Here is a basic version of my code.

```
Screen_size()

$(window).resize(function() {
    Screen_size()
});

function Screen_size(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w <= 710){
        Mobile();
    }

    if (w > 710){
        Desktop();
    }
}

function Mobile(){
    console.log('Mobile');
    $( "#open" ).click(function(e) {
        console.log('Open Mobile');
    });
}

function Desktop(){
    console.log('Desktop');
    $( "#open" ).click(function(e) {
        console.log('Open Desktop');
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, the resize event happens thousands of times when you resize the browser, maybe even millions of times, and every single time you add another `click` event handler, and it adds up.

Comment: Thanks that's good to know whats the best option to remove it?

Comment: Checking the window size isn't really very accurate, I could have a small browser window open on my 27" screen, and you'd think I was on my phone. Anyway, it's really an X/Y problem, what you should be doing is just checking the window size when you click -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gpyeyqgb/

Comment: Well either you just bind the events and do the check there or you need to unbind everything and rebind.

Comment: so is there a way just to stop everything in the desktop function when the mobile on is called making everything in the desktop one obsolete. as if it wasn't even called?

Comment: Either you're on a mobile phone, or you're on a desktop, it doesn't suddenly change.

Comment: You can say `$("#open").off("click").click(...)` to remove the previous click handler and then bind a new one, but in my opinion it would be better to just bind a single click handler once and move the `if` test inside the click handler (and not have a resize handler).

Comment: Awesome thanks will look into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for window resize .. just make a click event like this

```js
$( "#open" ).on('click', Screen_size);
    
function Screen_size(){
  var w = $(window).width();
  (w <= 710) ? Mobile() : Desktop() ;
}

function Mobile(){
  console.log('Open Mobile');
}

function Desktop(){
  console.log('Open Desktop');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="open">Click</button>
```